# deeplearing4j with SVHN dataset

Tags: deeplearning4j

I try to model a CNN  with deeplearing4j using SVHN dataset (http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/), in particular I'm using

> Format 2: Cropped Digits

This is matlab's files and each one contains a struct with a tensor (4-D) and an array with label. I would open this one into my deeplearing4j code, so I wondered and I find this class `MatlabRecordReader.java` into `deeplearning4j/DataVec` (https://github.com/deeplearning4j/DataVec/blob/master/datavec-api/src/main/java/org/datavec/api/records/reader/impl/misc/MatlabRecordReader.java) but I can't understand how use it. Anybody has experience whit this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see the DL4J community on Gitter. It's active and there are 3500 engineers there. https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference for "datavec":
http://deeplearning4j.org/DataVec
So if you look at:
http://nd4j.org/tensor

All of deeplearning4j's neural nets are written using nd4j (matlab for java) so this should be pretty easy to map.

You'll see it more or less maps to matlab.
What might be easier is if you could just write out the values as a csv
and reshape them to be the proper value instead. If you use c ordering it should work fine.

If you do that you can just use the csvrecord reader.

That matlab record reader hasn't been used by a lot of people and I think may only work with matrices (it's been a while)

I would try the csv one first.

Comment: thanks @adam I have already had seen this resources, but I would have some explanation about MatlabRecordReader because I can't using it correctly with dataset of SVHN

Comment: You ignored my reply. I explicitly said how you could output your data. I *maintain* dl4j and I'm telling you that that matlab reader isn't very robust. That's why I'm offering you an alternative. There's nothing to explain here. I gave you a solution for how to load vectors in to nd4j.

Comment: Ok @adam, thanks for your  suggestion! Well, in your way a correct approach is:
1. load dataset
2. reshape and convert it into csv
3. use *csvrecord reader* in dl4j